# Adding the router package to Meteorite gives an error

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I've been going through the discover Meteor book. So far so good, but trying to add a router package gives me the error below. I tried removing the packages, but to no avail. I was unable to find someone with a similar problem..

```
$ mrt add router

✓ router
    tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git#v0.6.1
✓ page-js-ie-support
    tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-page-js-ie-support.git#v1.3.5
✓ HTML5-History-API
    tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-HTML5-History-API.git#v4.1.2

Done installing smart packages

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/meteor.js:145
          throw error;
                ^
Error: Command failed: => Errors while scanning packages:

While reading package from `/Users/flowen/Documents/_htdocs/microscope/packages/HTML5-History-API`:
error: Package names can only contain lowercase ASCII alphanumerics, dash, dot, or colon, not "H".

While reading package from `/Users/flowen/Documents/_htdocs/microscope/packages/router`:
package.js:21:9: Package names can only contain lowercase ASCII alphanumerics, dash, dot, or colon, not "H".

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:637:15)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:948:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually with Meteor 0.9.* I think meteor-router is no longer in use.  Meteor is looking to implement iron-router which can be obtained by meteor add iron:router.

Also, with the newer versions of meteor mrt is no longer needed.  You can get all the packages off the atmospere repo with the meteor add command.

Comment: Thanks! that explains a lot. I couldn't continue because of these strange errors and I guess the book 'discover meteor' is now out of date?

Comment: isn't there any solution?

Comment: there is: just rename HTML5-History-API to html5-history-api in the package.js and the folder/symlink, too.

Answer (score 0):

I admit, I was a bit too fast with submitting my question. But perhaps this answer will help others.

Just rename the package to lowercase letters and also the reference in package.json (all path's are displayed by the error).

Hard to believe though such an error exists and only I had this?

Answer (score 0):

to make the package run again just rename HTML5-History-API to html5-history-api in the package.js and the folder/symlink, too